# Not able to see command prompt when we run a Beanshell Script in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmx, jmeter-5.0

I saw in a video that we can open command prompt with JMeter and see the log which is printed by Beanshell Script in JMeter version 4, how can we see that in JMeter version 5
[image]

I tried different options in JMeter but was not able to see the command prompt opened.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [System.out.println("Hello");](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) function the output goes to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))  - the command prompt or terminal window where you did launch JMeter from

[image]

If you want to see the output in the log viewer window / [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) you should use `log.info("Hello");` instead

Also I would recommend reconsidering using Beanshell as it's [recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter context

Comment: Yes I want to see the System.out.println("Hello"); in terminal, how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Open JMeter in using the Jmeter.bat file, a command prompt will open in the background.

[Jmeter.bat reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8q2y.png)

Once you run you BeanShell Sampler code you will get the output on the already opened command prompt.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35496304)